# OpenCV Histogram Backprojection Alternative

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram

I start with creating an initial mask of an object in an image. Using this mask, a histogram is created which is then used to process subsequent images.

I use the calcBackProject function to find pixels in the image that belong to the histogram. The problem I am having is that too much of the image is being accepted because certain objects are similar to the color of the initial object. Is there any alternative to calcBackProject? In my application, I can't afford to get objects that do not belong. All of this assumes that I have a perfect initial mask.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to track an object, and it can be very difficult.  Within OpenCV you may want to try the meanshift/camshift tracker to see if these are any better.  If not then you may have to stray out of the opencv world and try tracking-learning-detection frameworks.

**Meanshift/Camshift/etc in OpenCV**

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/video.html
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_meanshift/py_meanshift.html

**Tracking-Learning-Detection in C++:**

STRUCK: http://www.samhare.net/research/struck (uses opencv)

**Tracking-Learning-Detection in Matlab:**

Preditor: http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/tld.html

Comment: While these are very nice methods, I am not sure if they are viable for my application. Without getting too far into specifics, my application requires recognition of an initial object of certain specifications(and example could be a face or hand). After this, only a very small portion of the object is seen and the background is dynamic. The problem is determining if this very small portion belongs. Shape is constantly changing so the only thing that I can think of is to characterize the object by the color space of the object and against the background. This seems to lead to inaccuracy

Comment: @user3157892 that is exactly the goal of a TLD framework, the learning part updates the model to account for the view point point changes.  But obviously it wont work in ludicrously hard conditions.